# How to make the `url` package respect fontspec font options (stylisticset) with LuaLaTeX

Tags: fontspec, urls, luaotfload

I use the inconsolata zi4 font as the monospace font in my document but use the curved l as well as the straight quote thought the stylisticset option in fontspec. however, when using the `url` package and compiling using `lualatex`, these options are ignored and the glyphs used are the default ones:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[StylisticSet={1,3}]{Inconsolata zi4}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\texttt{`/usr/local/lib/2015'} % using mono font directly

\path{`/usr/local/lib/2015'} % through the url package

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The `path` one should look like the `texttt` one which obey the fontspec options. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I don't have the font but using another mono font in my computer (Courier New), the fonts are the same in both those lines. Maybe it's an issue with  that font?

Comment: it is possible. although courier does not have stylisticset options so not quite relevant in this case. The font comes directly in texlive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My feeling is that `luaotfload` makes LuaTeX ignore the choice of stylistic sets when the font is used in math mode.

In order to prove my claim, I did

```
\mathcode``=\numexpr"7000+\mathcode``\relax
```

and tried `` $\mathtt{`}$ ``, which resulted in the curly backquote no matter what stylistic set in used in the definition of the mono font. Note that `url` typesets the URL using math mode.

As such, this seems a bug in `luaotfload` or in LuaTeX.

Workaround: typeset the quotes inside an `\mbox`.

```
\documentclass[border=3,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[StylisticSet={1,3}]{Inconsolatazi4}

\usepackage{url}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{%
  \do\`{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\`}}%
  \do\'{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\'}}%
  \do\l{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\l}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\texttt{`/usr/local/lib/2015'} % using mono font directly

\path{`/usr/local/lib/2015'} % through the url package

\setmonofont{Inconsolatazi4}

\texttt{`/usr/local/lib/2015'} % using mono font directly

\path{`/usr/local/lib/2015'} % through the url package

\end{document}
```

[image]

This will work also with XeLaTeX, although this engine doesn't need the hack, so the more complicated

```
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\makeatletter
\ifluatex
  \g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{%
    \do\`{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\`}}%
    \do\'{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\'}}%
    \do\l{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\l}}%
  }
\fi
\makeatother
```

is not really necessary.

Comment: You'll have to do the same for the 'l' as well, and any other stylistic variant.

Comment: @AlanMunn I didn't notice the ‘l’. I'll fix it.

Comment: @egreg That indeed works. For completeness, one also should add `\do\0{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\0}}%` for the unslashed `0` with stylisticset 2 (I don't use that one but it is there).

Comment: I will accept this answer as it solves my problem. But as you say, it is a bug somewhere in lualatex or luaotfload and it probably be a good thing to report it. I guess the lualatex-dev mailing list is the appropriate place to do so.