# URL removes Slashed Zero

Tags: luatex, fontspec, urls, xurl

I am using the `fontspec` and `xurl` packages. I have found that the command `\url` removes the `Numbers=SlashedZero` OpenType feature. Obviously, I want the Slashed Zero to work, even when typesetting urls.

I provide a MWE where I demonstrate the issue with three different monospaced fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%These fonts are available for free on Google Fonts.
%\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}[Numbers=SlashedZero]
%\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}[Numbers=SlashedZero]
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}[Numbers=SlashedZero]
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{xurl}
\begin{document}
\texttt{01234567890123456789}
\par
\url{01234567890123456789}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: 2023-02-09. I have done some testing and found that the suggestion by der_herr_g fixes the Slashed Zero issue, but also prevents linebreaking at the Slashed Zero. I provide a MWE to demonstrate the issue. If I comment the `\makeatletter\makeatother`, then the line breaking works correctly, but there is no Slashed Zero.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%These fonts are available for free on Google Fonts.
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}[Numbers=SlashedZero]
%\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}[Numbers=SlashedZero]
%\setmonofont{Fira Mono}[Numbers=SlashedZero]
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xurl}
\makeatletter
  \g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{%
    \do\0{\mbox{\UrlFont\char`\0}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
%\texttt{01234567890123456789}
%\par
%\url{01234567890123456789}
%\par
\texttt{000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}%70 zeroes
\par
\url{000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}%70 zeroes
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I compile your MWE, both the `\texttt{}` and the `\url{}` command output slashed zeros — both locally and on Overleaf. Am I misunderstanding the issue?

Comment: I will add that I am compiling via `LuaLaTeX` and that I am using TeXworks and that my TeXworks is up to date. I just checked on my machine: the `\texttt{}` gives me the slashed zero while `\url{}` does not.

Comment: Right, it seems like a LuaLaTeX issue (I was checking things with XeTeX).

Comment: I updated my answer with a partial solution for the linebreak issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}[Numbers=SlashedZero]

\usepackage{xurl}

% ADD THIS (edited; see below)
\makeatletter
  \g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{%
    \do\0{\allowbreak\mbox{\UrlFont0}}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Original test case
\texttt{01234567890123456789} \par
\url{01234567890123456789} \par

% Breaking a URL on a slashed zero
\texttt{000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000} \par
This is looking fine: 
\url{000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000} \par
Here we still have a problem (line breaks a bit too late): \par
\url{000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}

\end{document}
```

All credit should go to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251158/97669) and the comment by ArTourter.

**Edit (2023-02-10):** Adding a simple `\allowbreak` seems to fix the linebreak issue in many cases. [Also, `\UrlFont0` works just as well as `` \UrlFont\char`\0 ``.] There are corner cases where the linebreak happens a bit too late, though.